# How to use Emgu.CV to capture video over RTSP protocol

Tags: c#, udp, video-capture, emgucv, rtsp

I'm trying to capture a video stream from IP camera over RTSP protocol using Emgu CV NuGet package in my WPF app. The problem is that open cv forces VideoCapture class to work over TCP protocol, but the video is streaming over UDP. Is it possible to configure VideoCapture to work over UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by switching from Emgu CV 4.1.1 to version 3.1.0